# MySQL service won't start

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I've just rebooted my Ubuntu server and MySQL just won't start for some reason! I'm using:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

I just get this:

```
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                         [fail]
```

Why might this be happening? Apache is running and my site works OK apart from the database connection. MySQL server is installed normally via synaptic.

---

I ran:

```
sh -x /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Which listed this among the output:

```
+ echo -e 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in\n/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!\n
```

I followed [the advice here](http://anthologyoi.com/computers/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socketerror.html) for creating the .sock file but no luck.

(Let me know any more information you need me to provide.)

---

Update: I ran `mysqld` since the output above mentioned it, and got this error:

```
100516 17:37:57  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Any idea what it means, or what file it refers to?

Comment: What does /var/log/daemon.log say in regards to mysql?

Comment: @andol: there's nothing in there about mysql at all. Also, `/var/log/mysql.err` and `/var/log/mysql.log` are empty.

Comment: my guess is that the socket doesn't have the correct permissions or that you are out of space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Success! As mentioned in the question update, running `mysqld` gave some errors. I found the files and realized that the entire `/var/lib/mysql` directory had the wrong owner (root instead of mysql). This was due to the partition swap and file moving I did.

So I ran:

```
chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql/
```

Then running `mysqld` followed by the regular MySQL start command fixed everything.

Thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

while restarting mysql run

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

and observe what's going on there. maybe you've run out of disk space on data / log partitions.

Comment: I *had* run out of disk space yesterday, but I swapped two partitions so there's plenty of disk space now. Could there be some issue related to that maybe?

Comment: Also, there's nothing in that syslog file from today, only yesterday morning, way before I did any of this.

Comment: Very strange there are no logs - what does df -h /var have to say ?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat reboot for a good measure

Comment: @Iain: it says Use% is 2%. The partition that I swapped it with is 4% used.